# Pronunciation of the plural of 'Ms'

Tags: pronunciation

The pronunciation of 'Ms' is /mɪz/. How about the plural of 'Ms' (i.e. Mss)? Will it be /mɪzɪz/ or simply /mɪz/ (pronunciation unchanged)?

Comment: Usually "Mss" is pronounced *"manuscripts"*. The plural of *Mr* is not written *Mrs*, the plural of *Mrs* is not written *Mrss*, and I don't think I've ever seen the plural of *Ms* written *Mss*. The [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Ms.) says the spoken plural is pronounced /mɪzəz/, and I agree (although it's  /mɪzɪz/ if you pronounce *roses* with an /ɪ/).

Comment: I can't think of any context where you would use plurals of Mr, Mrs, or Ms.  I think I've seen "Misses" and "Masters", to refer to a group of girls or boys, like "Would the young misses like to come in please?" or "The young masters have all been disciplined", and "master" has other meanings outside of the title of course.  But I've not seen it used with any adult titles.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, in the context of "the awards were presented to Ms. Smith and Ms. Jones", could you tighten that up to say "the awards were presented to Mss(?) Smith and Jones"?  If so, how would you write or pronounce Mss?

Comment: @PeterShor, the OED Online (http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/123118?rskey=mrEsU2&result=9 ) actually suggests Mss or Mss. along with Mses(.) as plurals for Ms(.), somewhat to my surprise—I looked it up because I was curious after reading your comment. I have heard it in speech (two syllables), but I assume in writing it would only be used before a very long list of names, e.g. "present were Mses. Smith, Jones, Johnson, Lee, . . ." Ed. because I can't figure out how to embed links.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I'd say no because a) it's not the convention and b) it sounds like "Mrs Smithandjones".  In answer to your second question, I just wouldn't pluralise "Ms", "Mrs" or "Mr" at all.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, me neither.  I'd opt for "Ms. Smith and Ms. Jones", if only two names and some other convention, I suppose, for more than 3 names.

Comment: I always thought that the plural for Miss was Misses. But written out in abbreviated form? I think you'd have to use the French convention as most formal events do. Mesdemoiselles (Mlles).

Comment: @MaxWilliams it used to be the convention, though, and recently enough that some people might want to continue to use it.  As to the plural of "Mr.": https://www.google.com/search?q=messrs

Comment: @phoog very good point about "messrs" - is that a french word?

Comment: @MaxWilliams yes, its unabbreviated form is *messieurs,* which is the plural of *monsieur.*

Answer (score 4):

Not all honorifics are noun adjuncts having singular and plural forms.

For comparison, consider *Honorable*, an adjective honorific. As adjectives do not have singular and plural forms, we would say

> 1. the *Honorable* Ruth Bader Ginsburg

and perhaps

> ?2. the *Honorable* Ruth Bader Ginsburg and Sandra Day O'Connor

but never

> *3. the *Honorables* Ruth Bader Ginsburg and Sandra Day O'Connor

Similarly, when used as honorifics, *Miss* (`ˈmɪs`), *Mrs* or *Missus* (`ˈmɪsᵻz`), and *Ms* (`ˈmɪz`) function like true adjectives and do not have plural forms. We would say

> 4. *Miss* Jane Marple
>   5. *Mrs* Phyllis Schlafly
>   6. *Ms* Gloria Steinem

but generally not

> *7. *Misses* (`ˈmɪsᵻz`) Jane Marple and Jane Bennet
>   *8. *Mrses* (`ˈmɪsᵻsᵻz`) Phyllis Schlafly and Nancy Reagan
>   *9. *Mses* (`ˈmɪzᵻz`) Gloria Steinem and Dorothy Pitman Hughes

The collisions of pronunciation alone are an insurmountable barrier to plural forms of these words developing. When a plural honorific analogous to *Mrs*, *Miss*, or *Ms* is needed, we sometimes say *mesdames*:

> 10. *Mesdames* (`meɪˈdɑm`) Gloria Steinem and Dorothy Pitman Hughes

Or else we avoid the issue by saying the honorific before each name individually:

> 11. *Ms* Gloria Steinem and *Ms* Dorothy Pitman Hughes

For more on the history and usage of these honorifics, check out their Wikipedia articles.